# Render SelectTag() with options from an array of models

Tags: go, buffalo

I have a `User` model and a `App` model in my application. `App` has a `belongs_to` relation with `User` model.

In the template `apps/new.plush.html` I need to render the list of users as a drop down selection. I have implemented `forms.Selectable` interface like below in the `User` model -

```
func (a *User) SelectLabel() string {
    return a.Name
}

func (a *User) SelectValue() interface{} {
    return a.ID
}
```

The `New()` action in `apps.go` looks like this -

```
func (v AppsResource) New(c buffalo.Context) error {
    tx, ok := c.Value("tx").(*pop.Connection)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("no transaction found")
    }

    users := &models.Users{}
    if atErr := tx.All(users); atErr != nil {
        return c.Error(http.StatusNotFound, atErr)
    }

    c.Set("users", users)
    c.Set("app", &models.App{})

    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, r.HTML("/apps/new.plush.html"))
}
```

Now, how do I write the Select Tag to render the options from the `users` array?

Below is not working -

```
<%= f.SelectTag("UserID", {options: users})%>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution from #buffalo slack channel. The issue is with -

```
func (a *User) SelectLabel() string {
    return a.Name
}

func (a *User) SelectValue() interface{} {
    return a.ID
}
```

These should not be pointer methods. The correct version is -

```
func (a User) SelectLabel() string {
    return a.Name
}

func (a User) SelectValue() interface{} {
    return a.ID
}
```